# Regarding the Miller-Rabin test

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, cryptography

I have a short question regarding the Miller Rabin test:

Suppose we want to test the primality of $n \ge 3$. When we pick a random integer $a$ from $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ and see that $a$ is a witness to the primality of $n$,  why do we not update the set $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,n-1\} \setminus {a}$, i.e. delete $a$? I have looked in multiple text books and on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test), this is never done anywhere, but if I am not mistaken this is necessary to ensure that the test works properly. Could you explain this to me?

Comment: Of course, it makes sense to use no duplicates, but if we choose the bases randomly, the probability given by $\frac{1}{4^k}$ still holds because the risk that the composite passes the base is always at most $\frac{1}{4}$ For large $n$, duplicates are very unlikely anyway, so it makes almost no difference. For small $n$, deterministic variations are known.

Comment: Remark : If we have a "random" number without any particular structure with at least $100$ digits, it is shown in the prime page of Chris Caldwell how extremely reliable a single WEAK fermat-test with a random base is. Primes generated this way are sometimes called "industrial primes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are $k$ of $n-1$ witness to give the result that $n$ is not a prime, then test $u$ random number, we have $(\frac{n-1-k}{n-1})^u$ probability to fail. If we restrict that these numbers are distinct, then we have $\binom{n-1-k}{u}/\binom{n}{u}$ probability to fail. Since $u\ll n-1-k$ (If $n$ is large, then we should only test $O(\log^2 n)$ times), this two probability is almost same (cause $\binom{n-1-k}{u}/\binom{n}{u}=(n-1-k)^{\underline u}/n^{\underline u}$, where $n^{\underline u}=n(n-1)\cdots(n-u+1)$).

From another perspective, if we choose random numbers between $[1,n]$, then we need about $\Theta(\sqrt n)$ times to get two same number (the birthday paradox). In Miller-Rabin test you actually test $u\ll\sqrt n$ times, so it's unnecessary to delete numbers already tested.

These explanation may not work for small $n$, but if $n$ is small we can only test some fixed numbers, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Testing_against_small_sets_of_bases).